# Retrieving javascript variable from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am trying to get the variable value of `data.latitude` (line 483) out of the jquery.getAddress-4.0.0.js file into my index.html. I created a new line after line 483 and created a new variable in which I set `data.latitude` by doing so:

```
if (self.$output_fields.latitude) {
self.$output_fields.latitude.val(data.latitude || "");
var userLatitude = data.latitude;
}
```

Then in index.html I use the following code to retrieve the variable

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#postcode_lookup').getAddress({
        api_key: '', 
        output_fields:{
            line_1: '#line1',
            line_2: '#line2',
            post_town: '#town',
            postcode: '#postcode',
            latitude: '#latitude',
            longitude:'#longitude'
        },
        onAddressSelected: function(elem,index){
            console.log(userLatitude);
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to work and I get the following error:
getaddress.html:51 Uncaught ReferenceError: userLatitude is not defined

Here is the link to the .js file
https://getaddress-cdn.azureedge.net/scripts/jquery.getAddress-4.0.0.js

Does anyone know how to get this variable into the index.html file?

Comment: You can't declare a variable in one function and reference it in another else except under very specific circumstances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

According to the type of error, it doesn't seem to be the problem of the .js file- https://getaddress-cdn.azureedge.net/scripts/jquery.getAddress-4.0.0.js .

Also, `var userLatitude = data.latitude;` line is not mentioned in the .js file i.e.   https://getaddress-cdn.azureedge.net/scripts/jquery.getAddress-4.0.0.js .

So most probably, compiler was unable, to find userLatitude varchar variable.

Make sure you are including the below line specifically at the end of the body content (i.e. just before the ending of the body tag) of the HTML code/file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your js file path>"></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I made a copy of that file on my computer and added that line myself. It just seems that I cannot get the variable outside of that function

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
if (self.$output_fields.latitude) {
   self.$output_fields.latitude.val(data.latitude || "");
   window.userLatitude = data.latitude;
}
```

Then you can get like window.userLatitude

Comment: when I do that then console.log outputs 'undefined'

Comment: if you're put this variable in window instance, I don't know why you can't able to get this. 

Try to read on chrome console for window.userLatitude after load the code. Or put a breakpoint on this line, that create this window variable to know if the code it's passing from there.